# SharePoint 2013 cannot import Thesaurus for synonyms

Tags: 2013, powershell, search, enterprise-search

When I try the commands in the ISE (ran as Admin) on the SharePoint 2013 server:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell

$searchApp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication -Identity cd87de08-d8d9-449b-aed7-0f3ebbd01884
Import-SPEnterpriseSearchThesaurus -SearchApplication $searchApp -Filename "\\vp-shp01\Synoniemen\synoniemen.csv"
```

I receive the following error:

[image]

```
Dictionary import in progress.
Failed to import custom dictionary Microsoft.UserDictionaries.Thesaurus.
Failure: Evaluation failure. An evaluation thread threw an exception. (Exception type: System.IO.IOException. Exception message: error CS2001: Source file 'Search\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpE85D.tmp' could not be found
```

).

And

```
Dictionary import in progress.
Failed to import custom dictionary Microsoft.UserDictionaries.Thesaurus.
Failure: Evaluation failure. An evaluation thread threw an exception. (Exception type: Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.DataModel.EvaluationException. Exception message: Evaluation failed in operator DictionaryRepositoryWriterLangInDependent of type DictionaryRepositoryWriter).
```

The Synoniemen.csv:

```
Key,Synonym,Language
IE,Internet Explorer
Internet Explorer,IE
UN,United Nations,en
UN,Vereinte Nationen,de
```

Everyone has Full Control on NTFS and the Share \vp-shp01\Synoniemen and on the file itself

The SharePoint Server Search Service is started and the admin user running the PS script has full control on the SharePoint Server Service Application.

How can I get the synonyms imported?